# Letting user define name of table in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to let a user build lists of vocabulary, and then save different lists of vocabulary from an array in a database. For the user to be able to name each list, I try to give each table a name that the user defines. Then transferring the "nameOfList-String variable" to be the name of the table. This however gives me an error when compiling. For the sake of simplicity I have made an alternative bit of code here which in principle represents what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] exampleArray = {"one", "two", "three"};
String nameOfList = "listName";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase database 
    =getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("exampleDatabase", 
    MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
      '"+nameOfList+"'(numbers VARCHAR)");

    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++){
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO '"+nameOfList+"' VALUES 
        (exampleArray[x])");
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "[x]": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 'listName' VALUES (exampleArray[x])

How can I take a user input as a String variable, and use the String variable to name a table in SQLite, and then fill the database with strings from an array?
Thankful for any help :-)

Comment: missing space after table name. Log your query and first verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to insert the string "exampleArray[x]" when I think you want the contents of element x of the array `exampleArray`.  So change the insert to:

`database.execSQL("INSERT INTO '"+nameOfList+"' VALUES 
        (" + exampleArray[x] + ")");`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}
```

You can find more information here: http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/
Hope this helps!